How to set different connection strings based on build configurations for debug sessions
I am trying to have different sets of connection strings based on the build configuration. (Debug, Release, Beta, LocalTraining, etc...) The use of Config Transform files, such as web.beta.config can easily acheive the goal during deployment, but I want the changes to also take effect when pressing F5 too, to help local debugging and testing.
I tried to update the connection strings during Application_Start. The Idea is to have an environment variable and update the connection strings based on it. The variable can be set in the deployment servers easily, but I can't figure out how to set environment variables based on $(configuration) for the sake of running locally. Further more, the way I find to update the config as shown below causes the web.config file to be modified, which I'm afraid of causing problems.
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
}
else
{
    config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}
var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString = "my connection string";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

Am I trying to acheive some unusual goal, or I just didn't find the correct way to do it? What is the correct way to acheive such goal?

There are methods that uses a template web.config file and uses TransformXml after build. However, the risk of needing to manually update the base.config after every Nuget package update is too large. And SlowCheetah just doesn't work for debugging for web projects.
Note: the application is on .NET Framework 4.8, not Core.

This issue is similar to this one. Please check if it helps.

The linked issue also mentions this only works with a build step that copies the correct file to the linked configSource location and woud get OP in the same situation being unable to use it while debugging without special (ms)build logic

"...  I can't figure out how to set environment variables based on $(configuration) for the sake of running locally." $(configuration) is an MSBuild property. You can 'get' but you can't 'set' an environment variable from MSBuild. But regardless, an environment variable 'set' in the build process would not be available in the debug session. The debug session will be a child process of Visual Studio.

Look at debug launch profiles. Per project the launch profiles are stored in Properties\launchSettings.json.

@jonathanDodds Yeah... I found some way to set the environment variable in MSBuild via UseTask in beforebuild but like you said the debug session can't see it... I'll look into the debug lauch settings. The json version only works for .net core but it does have a dedicated doc for .net 4.8

My mistake -- you did say the application is .NET Framework. With .NET Framework there are debug settings that can be set per configuration but environment variables may not be supported. These debug settings are stored in a <project-name>.csproj.user file which is intended to not be version controlled.

You can use ASP.NET Configuration Builders to accomplish this (also have a look if one of pre-built config builders mentioned in this documentation fits your needs!).
It allows you to create a class that will hook into the loading of web.config and modify configuration sections. I have a sample that demonstrates how to use a ASP.NET Core style appsettings.*.json configuration files to populate ASP.NET 4 AppSettings and ConnectionStrings at https://github.com/dasMulli/ConfigSampleWebApp
For your approach, you can create a custom class inheriting from ConfigurationBuilder that processes the configuration section:
public class MyConnectionStringConfigurationBuilder : ConfigurationBuilder
{
    // you can use #if / #elif etc to rely on build configuration or read enviornment variables to switch environments

#if DEBUG
    private const string DefaultEnvironmentName = "Development";
#else
    private const string DefaultEnvironmentName = "Production";
#endif
    public override ConfigurationSection ProcessConfigurationSection(ConfigurationSection configSection)
    {
        switch (configSection)
        {
            case ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection:
                // modify connectionStringsSection as needed
                // e.g. by reading the connection string from a different file or using one of the provided non-default connection strings with a "default" name that is used later on in your application
                return connectionStringsSection;
            default:
                return base.ProcessConfigurationSection(configSection);
        }
    }
}

This class can then be registered in web.config:
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="MyConnectionStringConfigurationBuilder" type="MyApp.MyConnectionStringConfigurationBuilder , MyApp"/>
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <connectionStrings configBuilders="MyConnectionStringConfigurationBuilder">
    <clear/>
    ... <!-- e.g. add "Database_Development" and "Database_Production" and set "Database" from one of these in the config builder. -->
  </connectionStrings>

  ...
</configuration>


Thank you so much! The use of preprocessor #IF helps me huge. One question is since I also want to separate connection string for BETA that could be in debug or release, I need a separate logic for #If RELEASE mode and #If DEBUG mode. What I do is combining your answer and have the release mode reads from environment variables set in the server, and debug mode uses a separate connection string file only for debug mode that is updated via TransformXml in the build action in MSBuild. That file doesn't need to be published or checked in git. Does this sound correct to you?

#if is testing a symbol, not an environment variable. For debug builds a DEBUG symbol is defined. For release builds there is neither a DEBUG nor RELEASE symbol. For .NET Framework in the project properties in the Build section you can add custom symbols in the Conditional compilation symbols. You could add two new configurations: "Debug Beta" and "Release Beta". These could be copies of the existing configurations with the addition of defing a BETA symbol. In MyConnectionStringConfigurationBuilder would be #if BETA and then #elif DEBUG.

See Conditional compilation

@JonathanDodds I see, DefineConstants works perfectly! Thank you! If I'm understanding what you meant correctly my current solution is working in release build because since the #IF DEBUG evaluates to false it uses the release logic (that reads actual environment variable set on the server to determine which config to use.) I do think using defining symbols is better here, since I don't have any other reason needing to add an extra step of reading from server env variables.

@SyndRain Yes, your understanding is correct :)
